# Possivel criar uma aplicaçao com Angularjs sem o Nodejs?

Tags: angularjs, node.js

Estou interessado em **AngularJs**, apos ter visto algums exemplos do seu uso. Gostaria de explorar esse **framework**.

Na maioria dos tutoriais que estou seguindo tudo começa pela instalaçao do NodeJs.

E obrigatorio ter o **Nodejs** instalado pra criar uma `app` com **Angularjs** ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sim, é possível.

Provavelmente os tutoriais que você tem visto pedem a instalação do NodeJS para ser possível usar o NPM (que é o gerenciador de pacotes do Node).

Você pode simplesmente baixar o Angular por outro gerenciador de pacotes ou baixar o(s) arquivo(s) diretamente. Dê uma olhada no [site oficial do AngularJS.](https://angularjs.org/)

Também é possível adicionar o Angular por um CDN, veja o exemplo abaixo.

```js
angular.module('hello-app', []);

angular.module('hello-app').controller('mainController', mainCtrlFn);

function mainCtrlFn(){
  this.hello = "Olá, mundo";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app-teste" ng-controller="mainController as ctrl">
    {{ctrl.hello}}
</div>
```